# TPOT freezes while optimizing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset

I have started working with tpot with dask. But the optimization always freezes at 0%. I have tried almost all the solutions suggested. But still no luck. Here is my code -

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import csv
import tpot
from dask.distributed import Client
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

target = list(csv.reader(open('target.csv')))
target_n = [] 

for i in range(len(target)):
     target_n.append(int(target[i][0]))

data = list(csv.reader(open('data.csv')))
data_n = []

for i in range(len(data)):
     tmp=[]

     for j in range(len(data[i])):
         tmp.append(np.longdouble(data[i][j]))
     data_n.append(tmp)  

  data_array = np.asarray(data_n)
  data_array = np.where(data_array < np.finfo(np.float64).max , data_array,np.finfo(np.float64).max)

data_array = data_array.clip(min=0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_array, target_array, train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)

tp = tpot.TPOTClassifier(generations=5, config_dict = 'TPOT light', population_size=10, cv = 5, random_state = 0, verbosity=3, use_dask=True, max_eval_time_mins=0.04, n_jobs = 20)
tp.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Any kind of suggestion will be greatly appreciated. By the way the size of my data is ~85MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things, if this is still an issue?:

Let's assume your using significant hardware, as you're using dask and n_jobs=20.

My guess is your generations and population size are too small to parallelise across that many workers so too smaller workloads are getting split up.

You may also need a line for multiprocessing when using multiple n_jobs. 
See the crash freeze heading [here](https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/using/).

Tricky to do dev tests by it's nature but TPOT recommends testing with at least a population size of 60, from memory.

Post your error message if this is still an issue.